# file not recognized: file format not recognized

Tags: linux, ассемблер, ос, fasm, ld

Столкнулся с проблемой при линковке двух объектных файлов.
Компилировал два файла: boot.asm и print.asm (при компиляции ошибок нет)
Но стоит начать линковать, то ld жалуется на невозможность распознания формата boot.o(на print.o тоже жалуется) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была решена c помощью команды cat [image: введите сюда описание изображения]